# Adding grid over Fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

I just started using Fabric.js (I have to say, I'm impressed).

I want to add a grid over the fabric objects. In the following code, I am putting my grid canvas right over on the Fabric canvas. The problem here is that, I now cannot move my fabric objects!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.2.0/fabric.all.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="height:480px;width:640px;border:1px solid #ccc;position:relative;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">

 <canvas id="rubber" width="800" height="800" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

    function renderGrid(x_size,y_size, color)
    {
        var canvas = $("#myCanvas").get(0);
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.save();
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;
        context.strokeStyle = color;

        // horizontal grid lines
        for(var i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i = i + x_size)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, i);
            context.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }

        // vertical grid lines
        for(var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j = j + y_size)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(j, 0);
            context.lineTo(j, canvas.height);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }

        context.restore();
    }

    renderGrid(10,15, "gray");
});

});//]]>  

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('rubber');
  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

  canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
  canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
  canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping that there is a way to do this in Fabric itself.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: does my answer solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will help you----

```
function draw_grid(grid_size) {

  grid_size || (grid_size = 25);
  currentCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
  currentcanvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();


  // Drawing vertical lines
  var x;
  for (x = 0; x <= currentCanvasWidth; x += grid_size) {
      this.grid_context.moveTo(x + 0.5, 0);
      this.grid_context.lineTo(x + 0.5, currentCanvasHeight);
  }

  // Drawing horizontal lines
  var y;
  for (y = 0; y <= currentCanvasHeight; y += grid_size) {
      this.grid_context.moveTo(0, y + 0.5);
      this.grid_context.lineTo(currentCanvasWidth, y + 0.5);
  }

  grid_size = grid_size;
  this.grid_context.strokeStyle = "black";
  this.grid_context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: How can i add fabric textfield in it ?

Comment: can you please share the fiddle? I'm not getting what is this.grid_context.

Comment: @UmeshPatadiya sorry, i don't have the code anymore, its a long time

Answer (score 13):

This two lines of code will work:

```
var gridsize = 5;
for(var x=1;x<(canvas.width/gridsize);x++)
                        {
                            canvas.add(new fabric.Line([100*x, 0, 100*x, 600],{ stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false, strokeDashArray: [5, 5]}));
                            canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, 100*x, 600, 100*x],{ stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false, strokeDashArray: [5, 5]}));
                    }
```

Comment: I just added a variable in order to control the cell size: `var gridsize = 10, cellWidth=30;
 for(var x=1;x<(canvas.width/gridsize);x++){
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([cellWidth*x, 0, cellWidth*x, 600],{ stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false}));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, cellWidth*x, 600, cellWidth*x],{ stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false}));
 }`

Answer (score 6):

A shorter version and more generic for copy/paste :

```
var oCanvas; // must be your canvas object
var gridWidth; // <= you must define this with final grid width
var gridHeight; // <= you must define this with final grid height

// to manipulate grid after creation
var oGridGroup = new fabric.Group([], {left: 0, top: 0});

var gridSize = 20; // define grid size

// define presentation option of grid
var lineOption = {stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,.4)', strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false, strokeDashArray: [3, 3]};

// do in two steps to limit the calculations
// first loop for vertical line
for(var i = Math.ceil(gridWidth/gridSize); i--;){
    oGridGroup.add( new fabric.Line([gridSize*i, 0, gridSize*i, gridHeight], lineOption) );
}
// second loop for horizontal line
for(var i = Math.ceil(gridHeight/gridSize); i--;){
    oGridGroup.add( new fabric.Line([0, gridSize*i, gridWidth, gridSize*i], lineOption) );
}
// Group add to canvas
oCanvas.add(oGridGroup);
```

Comment: Best answer. You may want to add "evented:false" to line options. That'll suppress all mouse interaction events triggering.

Comment: Hi, grid lines are not showing up on my canvas. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, the grid was not added because the group doesn't have dimensions here, since it's created before. Might be due to different versions. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636169/3370505) you can just rewrite so that the lines are built in an array and simply create a group out of that later. You can see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is -

```
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var j = 0;
var line = null;
var rect = [];
var size = 20;

console.log(width + ":" + height);

for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(width / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = i * size;
    rect[1] = 0;

    rect[2] = i * size;
    rect[3] = height;

    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5,
    });

    line.selectable = false;
    canvas.add(line);
    line.sendToBack();

}

for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil(height / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = 0;
    rect[1] = i * size;

    rect[2] = width;
    rect[3] = i * size;

    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5,
    });
    line.selectable = false;
    canvas.add(line);
    line.sendToBack();

}

canvas.renderAll();
```

You have to save all line objects for removing grid, or you can added all line objects to a group, and you can remove the group for removing grid, well I think this is not elegant one, but worked.

Comment: Tom, These lines are added as objects so when you want to send an object forwards or backwards these lines are also treated as valid objects. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't insist on generating your grid dynamically you might want to consider the native overlay image function that fabric.js provides.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('rubber');
canvas.setOverlayImage('grid.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

It won't hinder interactions with the objects on the canvas at all.

Comment: Actually, I need the grid to be generated dynamically. :O

Comment: @n2Code  how to set the overlay to the background.

Comment: There are two way 1) canvas.setBackgroundImage('../assets/pug.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)); 2) add overlay image immediately after you instantiated canvas and flag selectable to false

Answer (score 1):

I really liked @Draeli's answer, but it seemed it wasn't working with the latest fabric version. Fixed the old one and added one slight adjustment that was necessary for myself - centring the grid.

Anyhow, maybe someone else finds it useful:

```
const gridSize = 100;
const width = this.canvas.getWidth();
const height = this.canvas.getHeight();
const left = (width % gridSize) / 2;
const top = (height % gridSize) / 2;
const lines = [];
const lineOption = {stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)', strokeWidth: 1, selectable: false};
for (let i = Math.ceil(width / gridSize); i--;) {
  lines.push(new fabric.Line([gridSize * i, -top, gridSize * i, height], lineOption));
}
for (let i = Math.ceil(height / gridSize); i--;) {
  lines.push(new fabric.Line([-left, gridSize * i, width, gridSize * i], lineOption));
}
const oGridGroup = new fabric.Group(lines, {left: 0, top: 0});

this.canvas.add(oGridGroup);
```

this.canvas - this supposedly is the fabric instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, works with Fabric Js 4.
at the end there is 2 events listeners that append the grid when object moving and remove the grid when object move end. (improvement of @draeli answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936606/1727357 )

```
(function () {
    const gcd = (a, b) => {
        if (!b) {
            return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
    const gridWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    const gridHeight = canvas.getHeight();

    const oGridGroup = [];
    console.log(gcd(gridWidth, gridHeight));

    const gridRows = gcd(gridWidth, gridHeight);
    const gridCols = gcd(gridWidth, gridHeight);

    const lineOption = { stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,.1)', strokeWidth: 1, selectable: false, evented: false };

    for (let i = 0; i <= gridWidth; i += gridCols) {
        oGridGroup.push(new fabric.Line([i, 0, i, gridHeight], lineOption));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i <= gridHeight; i += gridRows) {
        oGridGroup.push(new fabric.Line([0, i, gridWidth, i], lineOption));
    }

    const theGorup = new fabric.Group(oGridGroup);
    theGorup.set({
        selectable: false,
        evented: false
    })

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (event) {
        if (event.target) {
            canvas.add(theGorup);
        }
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', function (event) {
        canvas.remove(theGorup);

    });

}())
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Answer is based on the code posted by rafi:

1. I have updated the missing grid_context.
2. Kindly replace "<your canvas Id>" with your canvas Id in string. For e.g. "myCanvas".
3. Usually, any operation you do on the canvas will clear out grid on the canvas, register the after:render event on fabric.js canvas to redraw it. So you can always see it.

   ```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(<your canvas Id>);
    canvas.on('after:render',function(ctx){
          draw_grid(25);
    });

    function draw_grid(grid_size) {
       grid_size || (grid_size = 25);
       var currentCanvas = document.getElementById(<your canvas Id>); 
       var grid_context = currentCanvas.getContext("2d"); 

       var currentCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
       var currentCanvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

       // Drawing vertical lines
       var x;
       for (x = 0; x <= currentCanvasWidth; x += grid_size) {
          grid_context.moveTo(x + 0.5, 0);
          grid_context.lineTo(x + 0.5, currentCanvasHeight);
       }

       // Drawing horizontal lines
       var y;
       for (y = 0; y <= currentCanvasHeight; y += grid_size) {
         grid_context.moveTo(0, y + 0.5);
         grid_context.lineTo(currentCanvasWidth, y + 0.5);
       }
      grid_context.strokeStyle = "#0000002b";
      grid_context.stroke();
    }
   ```

Comment: your answer is perfectly working for me... But my additional requirement is to zoom grid while mouse wheel zoom. Please guide me if you can. I am new in fabric.js